# Qt table widget, button to delete row

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtablewidget, qpushbutton

I have a QTableWidget and for all rows I set a setCellWidget at one column to a button.

I would like to connect this button to a function that delets this row. 
I tried this code, which does not work, because if I simply click my button I do not set the current row to the row of the button.

```
ui->tableWidget->insertRow(ui->tableWidget->rowCount());
QPushButton *b = new QPushButton("delete",this);
ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(ui->tableWidget->rowCount()-1,0,b);
connect(d,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(deleteThisLine()));
...


void MainWindow::deleteThisLine()
{
    int row = ui->tableWidget->currentRow();
    ui->tableWidget->removeRow(row);
}
```

How can I connect my button to a function in a way that the function knows which button (at which row) was pressed?

Comment: pass row number as argument when signal is emitted and in slot delete that row number received.

Comment: You might have issues if you do not queue this signal/slot because you would be deleting the row **and the button** while it is still handling the `clicked`signal from this button.

Comment: @user7431005 Try this connection : `connect(d, &QPushButton::clicked, this,&MainWindow::deleteThisLine);`

Comment: @user7431005 Have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the row we must first get the row, if we are inserting widgets inside the cells the `currentRow()` method will not return the appropriate row, in many cases it will return the row of the last cell without widget that has been selected.

For that reason you must opt for another solution, for this case we will use the `indexAt()` method of `QTableWidget`, but for this we need to know the position in pixels of the cell. when one adds a widget to a cell, this cell will be the parent of the widget, so we can access from the button to the cell using the `parent()` method, and then get the position of the cell with respect to the `QTableWidget` and use it in `indexAt()`. To access the button we will use the `sender()`.

When the current cell is removed the focus is lost, a possible solution is to place the focus again in another cell.

```
void MainWindow::deleteThisLine()
{
    //sender(): QPushButton
    QWidget *w = qobject_cast<QWidget *>(sender()->parent());
    if(w){
        int row = ui->tableWidget->indexAt(w->pos()).row();
        ui->tableWidget->removeRow(row);
        ui->tableWidget->setCurrentCell(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class, where you pass the created push button object and the row index. From your custom push button class, handle the push button press event and emit a custom signal (it will carry the index number) handled from the object where your custom pushbutton is created. Some related code are below, to give you a hint:

**.h**

```
class mypushbutton {
   explicit mypushbutton(QObject *parent = 0, QPushButton *pushbutton = 0, int index = 0);
   signal:
       void deleteRow(int index);
}
```

**.cpp**

```
mypushbutton() {
connect(pushbutton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(actionButtonClick(bool)));
}
actionbuttonclicked() { emit deleteRow(index);}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you're using the old slot/signal syntax and the question is about how he can get the row since his approach with `currentRow()` doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, `currentRow()` approach will not work and I'm not getting your point about old slot/signal ... what do you mean by that? `deleteRow(index)` needs to be catched from the creating object and he knows which row to delete.

Comment: You syntax is fine, but it's the old way that doesn't support many of the new features, such as lamba, etc. https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: Oh, I see. Got your point but I was having a hard time what is to do with the solution at the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Use this connection way to connect signal to a slot:

```
connect(ui->btnDelete, &QPushButton::clicked, this,&MainWindow::deleteRow);
```

And delete for example a row on call function:

```
void MainWindow::deleteRow()
{
    int row = ui->tableWidget->currentRow();
    ui->tableWidget->removeRow(row);
}
```

Comment: This can be also written as  `connect(d, &QPushButton::clicked, [=](){ ui->tableWidget->removeRow(ui->tableWidget->currentRow()); );` His solution is using `currentRow()`, but it does not return the current row. Either because of the inserted widget or it loses focus when the button is clicked.