# qt signal-slot on QCheckBox(es) previously added recursively

Tags: qt, checkbox, signals-slots, qcheckbox

I'm adding some checkBoxes recursively in tableWidget cells (always in column 1) on a specific function. The final nummber of those checkboxes is not defined and depends on the user input.

```
QStringList matID;
for(int i=0; i<matID.size(); i++
{
   ui->tableWidget->insertRow( ui->tableWidget->rowCount() );

   QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox();
   ui->tableWidget->setItem(ui->tableWidget->rowCount()-1,0,checkBox)
}
```

I would like to connect each one of them with a signal-slot connection which tells me which one has been checked.

Can anyone help me? I don't really understand how to do it...

thanks 
Giuseppe

Comment: Simply add in your for-loop: `connect(checkBox, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, [=](int state){ qDebug() << "Checkbox clicked" << state; });`

Comment: thank you, but like you said I can't say which one has been checked: I always get 2 or 0 whichever checkbox is clicked

Comment: I better explain myself: I would like to emit a signal which gives me the value of i (the row number where the clicked checkbox is)

Comment: You call getCurrentRow, but that may fail because you insert a QCheckBox. So you need to make a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46641743/qt-table-widget-button-to-delete-row/46643069

Answer (score 1):

There are four solutions for this problem. I'll only describe the cleanest possiblity.

The best solution is to actually to make your item checkable. You can do this by setting the `Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable` flag on the item using `setFlags()`, remember to also keep the defaults.

```
QStringList matID;
for(int i=0; i<matID.size(); i++
{
   ui->tableWidget->insertRow( ui->tableWidget->rowCount() );

   QTableWidgetItem *item = ui->tableWidget->getItem(ui->tableWidget->rowCount()-1,0);
   item->setFlags(item->getFlags() | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
}
```

Then, as explained in [Qt/C++: Signal for when a QListWidgetItem is checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252935/qt-c-signal-for-when-a-qlistwidgetitem-is-checked) (ItemWidgets are similar enough), you can then listen on `itemChanged` and check using `checkState()`.

The other methods would be:

- set an delegate for your column
- create a `QSignalMapper` to map your own `QCheckBox` pointers to some value identifying your rows
- Use the `QObject::sender()` member function to figure out which checkbox was responsible, and resolve it back to the row on your own.